# Are there any tools/processes for narrowing down the root caus of an extended TTFB/Server wait time?

Tags: server, webserver, cdn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently taken over the management of an e-commerce site. It is running on AWS (deployed through Elastic Beanstalk), based on Woocommerce/Wordpress with a custom theme and some custom javascript plugins that the previous agency designed.

The issue I am encountering is that the TTFB/Server Wait time is huge, varying from 4 seconds up to as much as 10 seconds. The website content itself is loading quickly, usually under 1 second depending on the connection. This means that if the page loads entirely in 5 seconds, 3-4 of those seconds are TTFB/Wait.

Pingdom Scan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6EsH.png

So far I have tried:

- Using a caching plugin (images, CSS, html, etc.)
- Delivering content from a CDN
- Keepalive Property applied where applicable
- Used GZIP to reduce content size
- Traceroute to make sure there are no weird DNS/routing issues
- Checked server resources history - we've never gone over 20% CPU/Mem usage.

So far none of these have helped significantly (although CDN helped speed up the site load AFTER TTFB).

If anyone has any ideas of some tools, resources or tricks to narrow down what is causing the TTFB delay I would be forever indebted. All of the articles I have found mentioned some of the fixes that I have already applied but I still can't seem to get the wait time down. I apologise in advance if I haven't included all the information necessary - this is my first dive into more complex server management!

Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but could you try flushing the output buffer early (or multiple times)? That might help narrow it down.